# Joining a ragged array in R

Tags: r, list, join

I often deal with objects of this form:

```
v <- list(one = c(a = 1, b = 2, c = 3), two = c(a = 10, b = 20, d = 30, c = 40))
```

and I would like to outer join these vectors by element name, to obtain:

```
  index value.x value.y
1     a       1      10
2     b       2      20
3     c       3      40
4     d      NA      30
```

I have written code to do this. In a nutshell, converts the vectors to data frames and reduces via successive merges. But I wonder if I have been reinventing the wheel and there is some function contained in a package, or in R base, possibly optimized. It seems a very common task.

Comment: In your real application scenario, I'm assuming that your lists comprise more than two items. Is that correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure this will be any simpler than your approach, but you could use `reshape2` , `lapply` and as.list.  I think the `melt` `dcast

```
library(reshape2)
dcast(melt(lapply(v, as.list)), L2 ~L1)
##   L2 one two
## 1  a   1  10
## 2  b   2  20
## 3  c   3  40
## 4  d  NA  30
```

Answer (score 2):

Here are two options in base R. They require converting your `list` into a `data.frame` first.

```
v2 <- data.frame(do.call(rbind, 
                         strsplit(names(unlist(v)), "\\.")), 
                 unlist(v))
names(v2) <- c("time", "id", "value")
xtabs(value ~ id + time, v2)
#     time
#  id  one two
#    a   1  10
#    b   2  20
#    c   3  40
#    d   0  30
reshape(v2, direction="wide", idvar="id", timevar="time")
#       id value.one value.two
# one.a  a         1        10
# one.b  b         2        20
# one.c  c         3        40
# two.d  d        NA        30
```

I don't know of a more direct way to split up the `names` that results from using `unlist`, but once that is done, the manipulation that you are trying to do becomes much easier.

Assigning new names is done to make the output more "tidy".

Answer (score 1):

Here's a base solution:

```
> do.call( merge,  list(v[[1]], v[[2]], by="row.names", all=TRUE))
  Row.names  x  y
1         a  1 10
2         b  2 20
3         c  3 40
4         d NA 30
```

For more a list of length >2 you can use `as.data.frame.table` to convert from a named vector to a two-column `data.frame`

```
> v <- list(one = c(a = 1, b = 2, c = 3), 
           two = c(a = 10, b = 20, d = 30, c = 40), 
           three = c(a = 1, b = 2, c = 3))
> setNames(Reduce(function(x,y) {
        merge(x,y,all=T, by ='Var1')},lapply(v, as.data.frame.table)),
         c('index', names(v)))

  index one two three
1     a   1  10     1
2     b   2  20     2
3     c   3  40     3
4     d  NA  30    NA
```

Comment: nice! After looking at this solution, I realized you can also do `Reduce(function(x, y) merge(x, y, by="row.names", all=TRUE), v)`. *However*, it seems like this only works if you have two list items. Is it possible to adapt this method to work with a longer list? I ask because I *suspect* that the OP has more than two items in their list (they mentioned using "successive merges").

Comment: `Reduce(function(x,y) {merge(x,y,all=T, by ='index')},lapply(v, function(x) data.frame(x, index = names(x))))` works for more lists with length more than 2

Comment: @mnel, good call on adding a conversion to a `data.frame` there to solve the problem. Prettying up the resulting names is also easy: `v2 <- Reduce(...etc...); names(v2)[-1] <- names(v)`. In terms of processing speed, this is faster than `dcast` (but that's not really a surprise to me).

Comment: You can also use `as.data.frame.table` to convert from a named vector to a two column data.frame `setNames(Reduce(function(x,y) {merge(x,y,all=T, by ='Var1')},lapply(v, as.data.frame.table)), c('index', names(v)))`

Comment: @mnel: You should have added the second section as your own answer.